# Determin if a racket program is in a sandbox

Tags: macros, racket, sandbox

Is it possible to determine if a Racket program is being run in a sandbox?

The reason I ask is because I have a Racket macro that creates a file. And the DrRacket background expander prevents a file from being created (as it should). However, in doing so, it causes an error to appear at the bottom of the window saying the file could not be created.

So, I would like to determine if I am in a sandbox, and if I am, don't create the file, and kindly finish up the macro.

Comment: Is it actually important to distinguish file-creation failing to due running in a sandbox, as opposed to failing for other reasons? If not, you could catch the `exn:fail:filesystem` (I'm guessing) using `with-handlers`. Otherwise, although you can call `current-security-guard`, the value AFAIK is completely opaque.

Comment: Yup, as far as I can tell `current-security-guard` is pretty opaque. And while you can use a new one, you need to give it a parent, so you cannot find what error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you cannot determine if you are in a sandbox. However, you do have a chance to catch the errors that are thrown when you try to perform a restricted operation. However, the catch is that you do not know what type of error is going to be thrown. So one thing that you can do is to just catch all of them. Use [`with-handlers`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=with-handlers#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._with-handlers%29%29) to catch the error and [`exn:fail?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=exn%3Afail%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._exn~3afail~3f%29%29) to catch all errors.

```
(with-handlers ([exn:fail?
                 (lambda (x) (displayln "failing cleanly"))])
    (make-temporary-file))
```

Be careful here that an error here may occur that is not related to being in a sandbox. For example, you could potentially get an error just because a file could not be created:

```
(with-handlers ([exn:fail:filesystem?
                 (lambda (x) (displayln "Coudln't open file"))]
                [exn:fail?
                 (lambda (x) (displayln "failing gracefully"))])
  (make-temporary-file))
```